# `Anko` gives exception AnkoException: Id is not set

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

Im trying to learn designing layout with `Anko`. I have set a layout using `Anko` as shown below

```
relativeLayout {
        val counterTextView = textView {
            text = "0"
            textSize = 24f

        }
        button {
            onClick {
                count++
                counterTextView.text = count.toString()
            }
        }.lparams {
            below(counterTextView)
        }
    }
```

I just need a relative layout with a TextView and a Button below the TextView.

The above code gives the following error

```
     Caused by: org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoException: Id is not set for android.widget.TextView{d8dedcd V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
    at org.jetbrains.anko.RelativeLayoutLayoutParamsHelpersKt.below(RelativeLayoutLayoutParamsHelpers.kt:60)
    at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want use `relativeLayout` params you must create id for view's have realtion so try this

```
relativeLayout {
    val counterTextView = textView {
        id = R.id.counterTextView // add this line
        text = "0"
        textSize = 24f

    }
    button {
        onClick {
            count++
            counterTextView.text = count.toString()
        }
    }.lparams {
        below(counterTextView)
    }
}
```

And you must create `ids.xml` in values folder

**ids.xml**

```
<resources>
    <item name="counterTextView" format="integer" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. BTW is it similar to adding `"android:id="@+id/counterTextView"` in XML?